# About SSL redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I have SSL installed. My site in browser also redirects to https:// but While loading it shows secure connection for a second and after that shows "Your Connection to this site is not secured". It still have https:// in url.
My htaccess file is as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: is your certificate linked to the vhost, and is the domain(s) on the certificate the same as the url you visit ?

Comment: @HugoRegibo Thank you, now it is linke to vhost. The problem now is that, it only shows "connection insecure" on home page, but on other page it shows secured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally what happenes is that if any site is accessed with https but the home page contains non secure links i.e. link with http, then the warning is shown.

In order to verify, you may use the tool - https://www.whynopadlock.com which shows how many links on any page are non secured.

Comment: I had few images with src attribute http:// so now its working fine. @Elizabeth Andesson Thank You.

Comment: Please set the answer of @Elizabeth Anderson as "correct/solved" if it helped you fix the issue.